# __appdir__ is different between cmd.exe and Start > Run

Tags: windows, cmd

I am getting different results when I use the following command from a cmd.exe shell and using Start > Run. This is running on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1339]. Why is this different?

```
CMD /C "ECHO %__appdir__%net.exe & PAUSE"
```

Using cmd.exe shell, the output is:

```
C:>CMD /C "ECHO %__appdir__%net.exe & PAUSE"
C:\windows\system32\net.exe
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Using Start > Run, the output is:

```
C:\windows\net.exe
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Explorer is expanding the system dynamic variable `"%__APPDIR__%"`, and the application directory of Explorer is "C:\Windows", i.e. the executable is "C:\Windows\explorer.exe".

Comment: `__APPDIR__` is an undocumented dynamic variable implemented by WinAPI `GetEnvironmentVariableW`. It gets computed from the image path of the current process. Another undocumented dynamic variable is `__CD__`, which is the current working directory of the current process.